# Oracle DBLINK clarification

Tags: oracle

Below is the oracle fixed user private dblink "create statement" as it is defined in the server. This is working fine. Now my question is, does the password mentioned in the statement PWD mean that it fetches the password from ldap or from oracle vault or it is the actual password itself?

[image: Create statement from the server]

Comment: Please have the code as text instead of image to allow copy and trial of that

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

For fixed user database links, the passwords are stored in the data dictionary. In former Oracle versions the password was stored unencrypted, but this has changed now.